# python -- Crash when trying to deal with unexpected input

Tags: python

So, I'm just fooling around in python, and I have a little error. The script is supposed to ask for either a 1,2 or 3. My issue is that when the user puts in something other than 1,2 or 3, I get a crash. Like, if the user puts in 4, or ROTFLOLMFAO, it crashes.

EDIT: okay, switched it to int(input()). Still having issues
Here is the code

```
#IMPORTS
import time
#VARIABLES
current = 1
running = True
string = ""
next = 0
#FUNCTIONS
#MAIN GAME
print("THIS IS A GAME BY LIAM WALTERS. THE NAME OF THIS GAME IS BROTHER")
#while running ==  True:
if current == 1:
    next = 0
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You wake up.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("")
    print("1) Go back to sleep")
    print("2) Get out of bed")
    print("3) Smash alarm clock")
    while next == 0:
        next = int(input())
        if next == 1:
            current = 2
        elif next == 2:
            current = 3
        elif next == 3:
            current = 4
        else:
            print("invalid input")
            next = 0
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I tested on python 2.7, replacing input with raw_input. It does not crash, but always posting invalid input.(because next is str not int)

Comment: @Herrington Darkholme: sorry, pretty new to python. I tried it, but how can I make next an int? Isn't it already being set to an integer at the very top?

Comment: `next = int(input())`. This converts str to int

Comment: still having some issues, update that first post. :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input()` not `input()` the latter eval's the input as code.

Also maybe just build a ask function

```
def ask(question, choices):
    print(question)
    for k, v in choices.items():
        print(str(k)+') '+str(v))
    a = None
    while a not in choices:
        a = raw_input("Choose: ")
    return a
```

untested though

Answer (score 0):

since the input() gives you string value and next is an integer it may be the case that crash happened for you because of that conflict. Try next=int(input()) , i hope it will work for you :)